# How can I test or decide if I need historical mortar to tuckpoint 100 year old bricks under brownstone steps?

Tags: brick, mortar, repoint

Is there a way to test or validate whether I need to buy more expensive historical mortar or can use something that is commercially available off the shelf from a big box store? Can I scratch the brick with a coin or something to test hardness?  I need to repair bricks under a large set of brownstone steps in a townhouse from 1906.  I had already had someone come out and repoint the outside of the stoop steps last year (I didn't think to look under the steps as well when they did it).

I'm thinking of doing it myself so am wondering what's an economical way of doing it since the historical mortar special ordered costs $100.

Image of the deteriorated brick mortar under the steps.

[image]

And this is the stoop from outside (which has already been tuck pointed).

[image]

Comment: Absolutely not an expert in this, so caveat emptor… can’t you just find an old recipe? Old mortar shouldn’t be rocket science. (This presumes that you *do* have old mortar.)

Comment: Is it a question of "what mortar will physically work?" Or is it "My local jurisdiction requires all outside repairs to be historically accurate?"

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact — I think the issue is that modern mortar is harder and doesn’t play nicely with old bricks. (I’ll skulk away in shame if somebody more knowledgeable comes by and disputes this.)

Comment: @Aloysius, yeah, I just researched it a bit. There's also a vapor permeability issue, where the more impermeable Portland cement based stuff can increase water in the brick/stone/etc. for freeze thaw damage. Sika's Canada website recommends less compressive strength than the existing mortar and more vapor permeability than the existing mortar: https://can.sika.com/en/construction/building-finishing/heritage-mortarsgrouts/recommendations/walls-build-between-1900-to-1940.html. Fuller exposition: https://beta.southglos.gov.uk/static/fb6a84c3835f68b6cc8ebf41b9d3be35/pointing-historic-buildings.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASTM C1713 promises an "annex" with historical mortar specs for US manufacturers at some point, but as far as I know this promise remains unfulfilled. This explains the high cost of historic mortars, I think. The Europeans have NHL standards in the meantime. Hydraulic lime has a limited shelf life and not much demand in the US (for the historically calibrated stuff, anyway), so maybe it will always be expensive.

You probably want NHL 3.5. I sourced a gallon from https://www.limeworks.us/product/st-astier-naturally-hydraulic-lime/ at 22 USD. That's about 2.5 gallons when proportioned with sand. That should be enough to repoint about 100 sq ft under their specs.

Comment: “an industry-standard used for historic restoration mortar, stucco, and Plaster with no harmful portland cement present or required”¹   Honestly, I never knew you could make a ‘cementitious’ or masonry-type mortar without portland cement! Where it would actually be of benefit. ¹

Answer (score 1):

If this was a historic building, the ideal answer would be to send a sample of the existing mortar to one of the labs which will analyze its contents and custom-mix a matching mortar. They can also give you a closer color match, if that's important to you

For my 1890's house, whick I already knew had lime mortar and case-hardened bricks, I just searched line mortar and bought a bag of off-the-shelf mix in roughly the right color range.

(For the fieldstone sub-foundation, which still wants repointing, modern cement is fine.)

See also online resources such as TOH.